# How to wrap nested query with filter by _index field in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query :

```
GET product,account/producttype,accounttype/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "keywords.keyword": {
                              "query": "search query"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "keywords.keyword.keyword": {
                              "value": "search query"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "keywords"
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": {
                    "value": "product"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
       {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "search query",
              "operator": "or",
              "fields": [
                "accountName^1.5",
                "description^0.8"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter": [
          {
            "term": {
              "_type": {
                "value": "accounttype"
              }
            }
           }
          ]
        }
       }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the above query I get this exception:

> "index": "account",
>             "caused_by": {
>               "type": "illegal_state_exception",
>               "reason": "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [keywords]"
>             }

Inside index account there is no nested object called Keywords.

In the past **Indices** query was used to solve this issue, but now it's deprecated.

Now as the query above shows: I am using filtering by **_index** but it still gives me that error.

So, could you please guide me to get rid of that exception and get my query working?

**PS:**

I am using elasticsearch v5.1.1

Comment: Hey, this might be a long shot but I got myself into the same trouble. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply adjust your url to point to the right index: `GET product/producttype/_search`

Comment: I have shortcut my query and it contains other queries to hit account index. I mean it's against multiple indices

Comment: I think it's your only option since the mapping of the two indices differs (one has a nested field, the other doesn't)